# function that returns all the j-th elements of i given items

Tags: excel, vba, paramarray

I want to write a function that returns all the j-th elements of i given items. The items contain single cells, ranges of cells or both.

While it is possible to return all elements (test1), the every first elements (test2), i fail to return the every second (or above) elements.

Given a Excel-Table

```
    B   C   D
2   X   1   333
3   X   2   666
4   Z   3   999
```

`=test1((B2;C2;D2);B3:D3;(B4:C4;D4))` returns `X 1 333 Y 2 666 Z 3 999`

`=test2((B2;C2;D2);B3:D3;(B4:C4;D4))` returns `X Y Z`

But `=test3((B2;C2;D2);B3:D3;(B4:C4;D4))` returns `Y 2 3`, which is wrong. It should return `1 2 3`.

[image]

The code of the VBA-functions is the following:

```
Function Test1(ParamArray argArray() As Variant)
' return all elements of all items = OK
    For Each outer_arg In argArray
        For Each inner_arg In outer_arg
            Test1 = Test1 & " " & inner_arg
        Next inner_arg
    Next outer_arg
End Function

Function Test2(ParamArray argArray() As Variant)
' return only the 1st elemtent of each item = OK
    For Each outer_arg In argArray
        Test2 = Test2 & " " & outer_arg(1)
    Next outer_arg
End Function

Function Test3(ParamArray argArray() As Variant)
' return only the 2nd elemtent of each item = FAILS
    For Each outer_arg In argArray
        Test3 = Test3 & " " & outer_arg(2)
    Next outer_arg
End Function
```

How do I address specific elements correctly?

Comment: @ScottCraner - only for single-area ranges

Comment: @TimWilliams i see the issue, you are correct it works for this specific case but not if they are separate ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @TimWilliams for showing me, what I misunderstood and what the cornercase (separate ranges) was. I wrote a solution, which loops over all elements with a simple counter. Works for me.

[image]

```
Function Test4(nmbr, ParamArray argArray() As Variant)
' return only the j-th argument (nmbr) of each element = OK

    For Each outer_arg In argArray
        cnt = 1
        For Each inner_arg In outer_arg
            If cnt = nmbr Then
                Test4 = Test4 & " " & inner_arg.Value
            End If
            cnt = cnt + 1
        Next inner_arg
    Next outer_arg
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reliably index directly into a multi-area range (except for the first area). For example:

```
? Range("B4:C4,D4")(3).address '>> B5, not D4 

? Range("B4,C4,D4")(2).address '>> B5, not C4
```

You could use something like this:

```
Function GetNthCell(rng As Range, n As Long) As Range
    Dim i As Long, c As Range, a As Range, tCurr As Long, tPrev As Long
    For Each a In rng.Areas
        tCurr = a.Cells.Count
        If tPrev + tCurr >= n Then
            Set GetNthCell = a.Cells(n - tPrev)
            Exit Function
        End If
        tPrev = tPrev + tCurr
    Next a
End Function

Sub Test()
    Debug.Print GetNthCell(Range("a1:A5,B1:B5,C1"), 6).Address '>> B1
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok. I failed to see that the objects i'm iterating over are still cell-adresses, not arrays of the values in the cells. So the numbers within the brackets are working  as an 'offset' (in your example: Range("B4")(2) >> B5). My example is misleading because the elements are next to each other; it wouldn't work if they were separated.

Comment: Unless you have a single-area range you can't treat it as an array.

Answer (score 0):

try this and [learn this](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/1005%20ParamArray.shtml)

```
Function Test2(ParamArray argArray() As Variant)
' return all elements of all items = OK
    For Each outer_arg In argArray
        For Each inner_arg In outer_arg(1, 1)
            Test2 = Test2 & " " & inner_arg
        Next inner_arg
    Next outer_arg
End Function

Function Test3(ParamArray argArray() As Variant)
' return all elements of all items = OK
    For Each outer_arg In argArray
        For Each inner_arg In outer_arg(1, 2)
            Test3 = Test3 & " " & inner_arg
        Next inner_arg
    Next outer_arg
End Function
```

Comment: This will not work reliably for non-contiguous ranges.  It's not about understanding ParamArray but how Excel handles indexing into multi-area (non-contiguous) ranges